# can't edit internationalization string in my rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, internationalization

I'm new enough to Ruby, and I've inherited a big project; up to now I've been coping just fine changing text on buttons/ forms/ text boxes by doing the following:

If I want to change the text on an object that says 'Text here', to something different, I search throughout my whole rails project for the string with 'Text here'. Normally I get a result in my locales/en.yml file, and I change the corresponding part of that file.

In the present case however I have a text field with 'Enter a location'. I want to change this to 'Put in an address' So I did a search for 'Enter a location' and in my internationalization file sure enough I see:

```
helpers:
enter_a_location: "Enter a location"
```

It's the only place in my whole project where this string of text occurs. But no matter what I change it to, I keep getting 'Enter a location', when I start my rails project. Even if I delete the whole enter_a_location thing altogether, it still comes up. It's really annoying! I thought I was getting the hang of this programming business. Any ideas what it could be?

The part of code where 'Enter a location' comes up is (in the text_field part):

```
<div class='address-area'>

<%= form_for current_user, :url => update_address_path, :html => {:method => :post, :class => 'form-horizontal', :id => 'address_form'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :address, :id => 'address_autocomplete' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :city %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :lat  %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :lng  %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag :changed %>
<% end %>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
gem 'json', '~> 1.7.3'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'compass-rails', '~> 1.0.1'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.10.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'inherited_resources', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '~> 0.0.7'
gem 'has_scope', '~> 0.5.1'
gem "best_in_place", "~> 1.1.2"

gem 'devise', '~> 2.0.4'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'linkedin'
gem 'omnicontacts', '~> 0.2.3'
gem 'SystemTimer', '~> 1.2.3'
gem 'resque', '~> 1.20.0'
gem 'resque-scheduler', :require => 'resque_scheduler'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.6.7'
gem 'rest-graph', '~> 2.0.1'

gem 'geokit', '=1.6.5'
gem 'geokit-rails3', '~> 0.1.5'
gem 'memcache-client'

gem 'forgery', '~> 0.5.0'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 1.7.0'
gem "amoeba", "~> 1.2.1"

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'

group :development do
  gem 'mongrel'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 2.12.0'
  gem 'capistrano-ext', '~> 1.2.1'
  gem 'ruby-debug-base', '=0.10.4'
  gem 'ruby-debug', '=0.10.4'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'letter_opener', :git => 'https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener.git'
  gem 'localtunnel'
end

group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'capybara-webkit', '~> 0.11.0'
  gem 'headless', '~> 0.3.1'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 0.7.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.9.0'
  gem 'email_spec'
end
```

Comment: Its probably part of a gem you use. Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Hi Sascha, posted my gemfile. For some reason I think Simple_form is the culprit. I had trouble with it before....

Comment: Hmm might be. Dunno that gem :) Can you post the Controller that handles that form post request? Somewhere should be validations concerning that address attribute

Comment: Got it sorted, changed <%= f.text_field :address, :id => 'address_autocomplete' %> to <%= f.text_field :address, :id => 'address_autocomplete', :placeholder => I18n.t('helpers.enter_a_location')  %>...and changed 'enter_a_location'. Don't know where it was calling it from in the first place, though. Thanks for help.

Comment: In views you can omit the I18n and just write t('').

Answer (score 3):

In some cases if the I18n module doesn't find the translation ( e.g. form attributes ) it falls back to a 'humanized' conversion of the translation's key. For instance 'enter_a_location' -> 'Enter a location'. So you wouldn't know whether it was using the set translation or fallbacking.

Or as Sascha mentioned it could be that another gem/engine/plugin you are using has the exact same translation key and is overriding the one you have set.

Right now it's hard to tell, because we can't see where the assignment of 'enter_a_location' is happening.